# Fixing Dynamic return text of a PowerBI / DAX calculation, error says 'table of mutiple values supplied... where single value was expected'

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm creating a PowerBI dashboard for supply chain backorders. There was a great video I saw from Microsoft demonstrating a Dynamic message card on their Destiny dashboard showing players and their favorite weapon, https://youtu.be/uHP7YJH526c?t=2438... I thought this would be a cool feature to implement but showing backorders with impacted Sales Reps and their Accounts. I essentially did a copy and paste of his code, but modified the variables as well as adding "affected product". Unfortunately, it doesn't work perfectly (some cases works) but a majority of the time I get this:

> Error Message: MdxScript(Model) (17, 125) Calculation error in measure
>   'Salesforce CC Backorder Report'[BackorderIQ]: A table of multiple
>   values was supplied where a single value was expected.

I get that it has to do with the fact that if I select a Sales rep, they may have multiple Products that are on backorder, so I tried variations in my maxBackorderForProduct variable (COUNT, COUNTA, COUNTX, COUNTAX, MAX, MAXX, MAXA)… so far MAXX is less likely to break it so I'm using that for now.

```
BackorderIQ =
VAR selectedRepName =
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'BOreport'[Sales Rep Name], TRUE )
VAR selectedActName =
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'BOreport'[Account Name], TRUE )
VAR selectedProduct =
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'BOreport'[Product ID], FALSE () )
VAR maxBackorderforSelectedAct =
    MAXX (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'BOreport'[Sales Rep Name],
            "Orders", SUM ( 'BOreport'[Back Order Qty] )
        ),
        [Orders]
    )
VAR maxBackorderforSelectedRep =
    MAXX (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'BOreport'[Account Name],
            "Orders", SUM ( 'BOreport'[Back Order Qty] )
        ),
        [Orders]
    )
VAR maxBackorderForProduct =
    MAXX (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'BOreport'[Product ID],
            "Orders", SUM ( 'BOreport'[Back Order Qty] )
        ),
        [Orders]
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'BOreport'[Sales Rep Name] ),
        selectedRepName & " has " & maxBackorderforSelectedRep & " backorders of " & selectedProduct & " at "
            & LOOKUPVALUE (
                'BOreport'[Account Name],
                'BOreport'[Back Order Qty], MAX ( 'BOreport'[Back Order Qty] )
            ),
        IF (
            HASONEVALUE ( 'BOreport'[Account Name] ),
            selectedActName & "'s has " & maxBackorderforSelectedAct & " backorders of " & selectedProduct & ", so give "
                & LOOKUPVALUE (
                    'BOreport'[Sales Rep Name],
                    'BOreport'[Back Order Qty], MAX ( 'BOreport'[Back Order Qty] )
                ) & " a heads up.",
            "Select a Product below, OR an Account or Sales Rep to the right."
        )
    )
```

I hope I can get the card to say the expected, "ACCOUNT2 has 50 backorders of ProductB, so give JOHN SMITH a heads up." which is the max value they would get, because JOHN SMITH could also have 20 backorders of ProductA from Account1.

Comment: What is the reason for using FALSE in this expression: FIRSTNONBLANK ( 'BOreport'[Product ID], FALSE () )?

Comment: Ah, this was also more experimentation. Had TRUE before and wasn't sure if it has to do with an exact vs approximate. Looks like I copied this version of code after trialing. Currently its at TRUE with same outcomes.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the error is caused by this line in the HASONEVALUE ( 'BOreport'[Sales Rep Name] ) block:

```
selectedRepName & " has " & maxBackorderforSelectedRep & " backorders of " & selectedProduct & " at "
```

This code has 3 elements:
selectedRepName, maxBackorderforSelectedRep, and selectedProduct

maxBackorderforSelectedRep can not cause any troubles because it always returns 1 value.

selectedRepName could cause troubles (it returns multiple values if no specific Rep is selected), but the formula protects against such scenario using HASONEVALUE.

selectedProduct is similar to selectedRepName, so it could return multiple values if no specific rep is selected, and you have no protection against such scenario. Hence the error.

A simple way to fix it is to add a similar protection:

```
IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'BOreport'[Sales Rep Name] ) && 
        HASONEVALUE ( 'BOreport'[Product ID]),
        selectedRepName & " has " & maxBackorderforSelectedRep & " backorders of " & selectedProduct & " at "
            & LOOKUPVALUE (
                'BOreport'[Account Name],
                'BOreport'[Back Order Qty], MAX ( 'BOreport'[Back Order Qty] )
            ),
```

And the same logic should apply to the second block:

```
  IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'BOreport'[Account Name] ) &&
        HASONEVALUE ( 'BOreport'[Product ID]),
        selectedActName & "'s has " & maxBackorderforSelectedAct & " backorders of " & selectedProduct & ", so give "
            & LOOKUPVALUE (
                'BOreport'[Sales Rep Name],
                'BOreport'[Back Order Qty], MAX ( 'BOreport'[Back Order Qty] )
            ) & " a heads up."
```

That should eliminate the error. However, I can't guarantee that you will get the desired behavior - the formula implies that you must select a specific Rep **AND** a specific product, otherwise it will return the default message.

Comment: I believe its intentional, my understanding was that if a user selects a from the Account column, the lookup value is going to find the Sales Rep within that filter. It seems to work in some cases but not often. When I implement the changes you mentioned, I get something like "JOHN SMITH has 10 backorders at JOHN SMITH".

Comment: It's very hard to help further without seeing your data, data model and visuals. DAX heavily depends on them. If your problem with the error is fixed, I suggest to close this question and post another one,  with updated code and descriptions of the new problems you are facing.

Comment: Actually, found part of the error was a typo on my end!